# How to remove a Specific Button from Flow Layout Panel

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am creating dynamic buttons, each has a unique Tag, each tag is then sent to a list box. i want to be able to select the tag from the list box and click a button to remove the button with that specific tag i tried making this code but no go....

```
Private Sub cmdRemove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRemove.Click
    Try
        Dim curItem As String = RmvList.SelectedItem.ToString()
        MsgBox(curItem)
        For Each Button As System.Windows.Forms.Control In Main.FloLay.Controls
            If Button.Tag = curItem Then
                Main.FloLay.Controls.RemoveAt(CurItem)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex1 As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

How can i Achieve this Feat? Thank you In Advance.

Comment: it would be easier to remove the button by name than TAG.

Comment: If you would give names to your buttons, you could do this in one line of code - `Main.FloLay.Controls.RemoveByKey(b.Name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RemoveAt` takes a number as parameter that is the index in the collection.
You have to do two things:

- Use Remove instead of RemoveAt
- Exit the for loop

So the code:

```
For Each Button As System.Windows.Forms.Control In Main.FloLay.Controls
     If Button.Tag = curItem Then
        Main.FloLay.Controls.Remove(Button)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

The first change is obvious, the second change is needed because you alter the enumerator when you remove the button and it would throw an exception if you try to continue the for loop after the deletion.

If you want to delete multiple items you can use the following trick:

```
For i = Main.FloLay.Controls.Count -1 To 0 Step -1
   If Main.FloLay.Controls(i).Tag = curItem Then
       Main.FloLay.Controls.RemoveAt(i)   'Here you actually provide the index!
   End If
Next
```

This will work because you don't alter any index yet to come be deleting an item if you move backwards through the collection.